# Fullscreen/scrolling background performance issues? (sorry for noobishness)

Tags: html, css

I'm sorry if this is a very common issue and/or I am missing something very obvious. My goal is to get my background to stretch across the whole screen while still scrolling with the rest of the page. The code I have now accomplishes that, but not without **severe** performance issues. The lag is atrocious. This is what I have so far:

```
<style>
html{
background: url(data/Background2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
</style>
```

I've also tried:

```
<style>
html{
background: url(data/Background2.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
background-size: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Finally, I've also tried this using a png copy of the same background, to no avail. Thank you so much for your time and consideration of my lowly noob problems.

Comment: What browser(s) are you experiencing this issue in? How large is the background image? And what kind of machine are you doing this on? Nothing immediately jumps out at me that could explain why this is slow for you.

Comment: Ahahaha. Yep, my background was 5000x3500 pixels. A little scaling in gimp fixed that just fine. Thanks Nathan!

Answer (score 0):

Check your image size. If it's too large either in pixel dimension or file size that can have a great impact on performance.